# Print the table of contents which is constructed using displayTag?

Tags: printing, displaytag

I am Using Struts2 and Display Tag in my Application. And I am Using navigation with partial="true" option in display table.

I have an another requirement that there is print option. If the User clicks on Print icon, the whole content should send all the records irrespective of navigation.i mean all records. Is it possible to achieve this? If only records in the page means.No problem i can do this. How can i send all the records for the print?